# can I use the hostname as a dimension in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Considering a site that exposes a dynamic range of hostnames...  Is there a way to use the hostname as a dimension in reports?

There are docs related to hostname, but not doing what I want.  I've seen things on filtering by hostsname in a profile, or having a profile filter that adds the hostname to the path GA uses.  I would rather use the hostname as a secondary dimension in reports.

One option I have is to add the hostname as a custom variable.  This seems wasteful though, as each request is only allowed 5 custom variables and the hostname is already transfered as part of the google analytics beacon.  I see the hostname included in the request to __utm.gif as querystring parameter utmhn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Any report's secondary dimension selectors will allow you to set `hostname` as a secondary dimension.
[image]
[image]
 You can even access it as a primary dimension by navigating to `Visitors->Network Properties->Hostnames` (or, in the new GA, `Visitors->Technology->Network->Hostname`).

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that one.